# Coordinates from text to array [preg_match]

Tags: php, sorting

Maybe someone can help me get coordinates from text to array?

I'm trying use `preg_match` but no success.

I can remove `geometry":{"paths":[[[**" and **]]}}]})`
then use some times 'explode' and get coo, but I don't like this idea

Coordinates:

```
"geometry":{"paths":
[[[485749.91999999998,6108180.6500000004],
[485722.35999999999,6108206],
[485691.14000000001,6108234.3099999996],
[485400.84999999998,6108513.1500000004],
[485368.60999999999,6108545.46],
[485301.53999999998,6108613.1900000004],
[484054.82000000001,6109868.9100000001],
[484051.17566666665,6109872.6840000004]]]}}]});
```

Comment: I would alter the string to valid JSON and then parse it using `json_decode()`.

Comment: OP has malformed json while pasting, i guess!

Comment: @Viral Yeah I think something's wrong with that string too. I will update my answer as soon as the string gets altered in the question by OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To figure out my approach in the comment above. Convert the string to valid JSON. Afterwards you can decode the string using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$jsonArr = json_decode('{' . substr($string, 0, -4), true);
$coordinates= $jsonArr['geometry']['paths'][0]);

var_dump($coordinates):
```

So you end up with an array of coordinate pairs:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(485749.92)
    [1]=>
    float(6108180.65)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(485722.36)
    [1]=>
    int(6108206)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(485691.14)
    [1]=>
    float(6108234.31)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(485400.85)
    [1]=>
    float(6108513.15)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(485368.61)
    [1]=>
    float(6108545.46)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(485301.54)
    [1]=>
    float(6108613.19)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(484054.82)
    [1]=>
    float(6109868.91)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(484051.175667)
    [1]=>
    float(6109872.684)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid Javascript object notation. Running it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) shows that it has an invalid array length. You might want to provide more context for your question.

Assuming you have something similar to the above but with *valid* JSON, you can use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method to convert a valid JSON string into PHP arrays and objects.